# How can I switch GCC and G++ versions when using CMake to build openpose?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, build, openpose

I'm trying to build OpenPose using the latest code on github. I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm following this guide: https://amir-yazdani.github.io/post/openpose/ . So far, when I try to build openpose using `make -j5` (after running CMake), I get an error

```
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:7024: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:376: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:86: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I see a lot of errors that look like

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:146: note: ‘_ArgTypes’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:145: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
435 | function(_Functor&& __f)
```

My guess is that this is related to the GCC version, since this looks like a use of variadic arguments, and that I'm using a too-modern version of C++. I have tried running `sudo apt-add repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` to install old versions of GCC and G++, but no version number I try seems to return an error that they have no installation candidates.

I have also tried `CC='gcc-8' CXX='g++-8' make j7`, and passing the same arguments when running cmake-gui.

Does this seem like I'm looking at the right reason for this error, and what might I be able to do to fix it?

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/11`, `CC='gcc-8' CXX='g++-8'` Why do you try to downgrade GCC 11? The issue is in CUDA. Here is the solution https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/issues/119#issuecomment-1113979878 or https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/issues/119#issuecomment-1231890237 or https://github.com/stotko/stdgpu/issues/337